# JavaScript turn string into json object

Tags: javascript, json

So, I have this function that works to get a JSON object but I want to make it simplier so I created a function to get the values of the JSON object. Why doesn't it work?

```js
var itemData = {
    weapon: function () {
        return {
            1: {
                'name': 'Dagger',
                    'extra_skill': 'none',
                    'cost': 500,
                    'attack': 5
            },
            2: {
                'name': 'Pickaxe',
                    'extra_skill': 'mining',
                    'cost': 25,
                    'attack': 5
            }
        }
    },
    getWeapon: function (value, x) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(value);
        return itemData.weapon()[x].obj
    }
}

// outputs: Dagger
console.log(itemData.weapon()[1].name)

// Get the name of weapon 1
// however, it outputs: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
console.log('Getting weapon... ' + itemData.getWeapon('name', 1))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSON is a **textual notation**. If you're writing JavaScript code, you're not dealing with JSON unless you're dealing with a string. There is no JSON, at all, in your question; and therefore, `JSON.parse` is not needed (and in fact, part of the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need JSON parsing at all to get this working, because there is nowhere where you have a JSON string that needs to be parsed.

Here is a working example:

```js
var itemData = {
    weapon: function () {
        return [
            {
                'name': 'Dagger',
                    'extra_skill': 'none',
                    'cost': 500,
                    'attack': 5
            },
            {
                'name': 'Pickaxe',
                    'extra_skill': 'mining',
                    'cost': 25,
                    'attack': 5
            }
        ];
    },
    getWeapon: function (value, x) {
        return itemData.weapon()[x][value];
    }
}

// outputs: Dagger
console.log(itemData.weapon()[0].name)

// outputs: Getting weapon... Pickaxe
console.log('Getting weapon... ' + itemData.getWeapon('name', 1))
```

Comment: I like how this answer also removes using `value` in `getWeapon`, since the intention of `getWeapon` seems to be to always return `name` anyway.

Comment: I understand what I was doing wrong now. Thank you.

Comment: It's good for classes/functions to each have a single responsibility, so I'd recommend the O.P. to clarify what specifically `getWeapon` is supposed to return. If the plan is to always return `name`, then `name` should be hardcoded in `getWeapon`. This avoids unintentionally making a typo when passing in `value`.

Comment: @DanF there is a tick symbol if you want to acept the answer, it gives the poster 'reputation' on the site

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I went to eat dinner then I forgot about it. Sorry! I always mark answers checked :-)